Проблема в Telethon совместно с Flask
Суть проблемы: есть простенькое приложение на фласке, в другом файле лежит скрипт с использованием telethon, при вводе в приложении текста, этот текст отправляется определённому пользователю, но в моём коде оно отправляет только один раз, при попытке ввести ещё раз вылетает RuntimeError: The asyncio event loop must not change after connection (see the FAQ for details) Нужно, чтобы при каждом получении данных функция отрабатывала
Вот код самого приложения на flask:
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect
from message_to_user import main
import asyncio


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def redirectFor():

    return redirect(url_for('getData'))


@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getData() -> str:

    if request.method == 'POST':

        text = request.form['text']

        asyncio.run(main(text))

    return render_template('base.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)

А вот функция на telethon:
import configparser
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.users import GetFullUserRequest

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

API_ID = int(config['Telegram']['API_ID'])
API_HASH = config['Telegram']['API_HASH']
bot_token = config['Telegram']['bot_token']

client = TelegramClient('bot', API_ID, API_HASH)


async def get_user(username):

    user = await client(GetFullUserRequest(username))

    return user


async def main(text):

    await client.start(bot_token=bot_token)

    user = await get_user('username')
    user_id = user.full_user.id

    await client.send_message(user_id, text)

    await client.disconnect()

